# How to make two lists out of two-elements tuples that are stored in a list of lists of tuples

Tags: python, list

I have a list which contains many lists and in those there 4 tuples.

```
my_list = [[(12, 1), (10, 3), (4, 0), (2, 0)],
           [(110, 1), (34, 2), (12, 1), (55, 3)]]
```

I want them in two separate lists like:

```
my_list2 = [12,10,4,2,110,34,12,55]
my_list3 = [1,3,0,0,1,2,1,3]
```

my attempt was using the `map` function for this.

```
my_list2 , my_list3 = map(list, zip(*my_list))
```

but this is giving me an error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your approach is quite close, but you need to flatten first:

```
from itertools import chain

my_list = [[(12, 1), (10, 3), (4, 0), (2, 0)], [(110, 1), (34, 2), (12, 1), (55, 3)]]

my_list2 , my_list3 = map(list,zip(*chain.from_iterable(my_list)))

my_list2
# [12, 10, 4, 2, 110, 34, 12, 55]

my_list3
# [1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 4):

A different, non-Pythonic approach:

```
my_list = [[(12, 1), (10, 3), (4, 0), (2, 0)], [(110, 1), (34, 2), (12, 1), (55, 3)]]

first = []
second = []

for inner in my_list:
    for each in inner:
        first.append(each[0])
        second.append(each[1])

print(first)  # [12, 10, 4, 2, 110, 34, 12, 55]
print(second)  # [1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [list comprehension (5.1.3)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

First number of tuple:

```
my_list2 = [tuple[0] for inner in my_list for tuple in inner]
```

Second number of tuple:

```
my_list3 = [tuple[1] for inner in my_list for tuple in inner]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try it:

```
my_list = [[(12, 1), (10, 3), (4, 0), (2, 0)], [(110, 1), (34, 2), (12, 1), (55, 3)]]

my_list2, my_list3 = map(list, zip(*[j for i in my_list for j in i]))
print(my_list2)
# [12, 10, 4, 2, 110, 34, 12, 55]
print(my_list3)
# [1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
my_list = [[(12, 1), (10, 3), (4, 0), (2, 0)], [(110, 1), (34, 2), (12, 1), (55, 3)]]

flatten = lambda l: [item for my_list in l for item in my_list]

list1, list2 = zip(*flatten(my_list))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
my_list = [[(12, 1), (10, 3), (4, 0), (2, 0)], [(110, 1), (34, 2), (12, 1), (55, 3)]]

my_list2 = [a for b in [[t[0] for t in my_list[i]] for i,n in enumerate(my_list)] for a in b]
my_list3 = [a for b in [[t[1] for t in my_list[i]] for i,n in enumerate(my_list)] for a in b]

print(my_list2)
print(my_list3)
```

Output:

```
[12, 10, 4, 2, 110, 34, 12, 55]
[1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a minimalist solution:

```
my_list = [[(12, 1), (10, 3), (4, 0), (2, 0)], [(110, 1), (34, 2), (12, 1), (55, 3)]]

my_list2, my_list3 = zip(*sum(my_list, []))

print(my_list2)
print(my_list3)
```

OUTPUT

```
> python3 test.py
(12, 10, 4, 2, 110, 34, 12, 55)
(1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3)
>
```

Comment: Maybe `my_list2` should be a `list`, not a `tuple` : `my_list2, my_list3 = [list(t) for t in zip(*sum(my_list, []))]
`

Comment: @AnnZen, that'd be up to the OP, though I'd be surprised if individual elements of `my_list2` and `my_list3` are going to be swapped around.  And if so, simply `my_list2 = list(my_list2)` or `my_list3 = [*my_list3]` seem reasonable enough, no need to introduce a comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

convert the list of tuples to an 2d array then slice the array

```
my_list = [[(12, 1), (10, 3), (4, 0), (2, 0)],
       [(110, 1), (34, 2), (12, 1), (55, 3)]]

a = np.array(my_list)
my_list2= np.array([])
my_list3= np.array([])
my_list2=np.append(my_list2,[item[:,0] for item in a])
my_list3=np.append(my_list3,[item[:,1] for item in a])
print(my_list2)
print(my_list3)
```

output:

```
[ 12.  10.   4.   2. 110.  34.  12.  55.]
[1. 3. 0. 0. 1. 2. 1. 3.]
```